# Create a list of resources English

Tags: feature-request

What do you think about create a list with resources of english grammar, English dictionary and books about english language.
Do you think It's a good idea?

Comment: It's a great idea! That's why we did it about three years ago :-)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't found it!